# using programmatic transaction control in CMT bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss5.x

I need to commit transactions from CMT bean by hand. There is a loop which processes multiple records and each record should be processed in its own transaction. I wanted to mark method transaction support as NOT_SUPPORTED and then control transaction from method. However I could not retrieve a `UserTransaction` instance neither from `SessionContext` neither injecting it as a JNDI resource `java:/module/UserTransaction`.

Are there any chance to process multiple records in CMT bean in their own transactions without introducing new BMT bean for such processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mess around transactions yourself if you use CMT.

I recommend you create a method for the operation needs to be in transaction, mark it as `REQUIRES_NEW`, then call it from the loop.

Everytime the method is called, the current transaction (if any) will be suspended and a new transaction will be started for the operation.

Something like this:

```
@EJB
SomeEJBLocal anotherme;

public void loop() {
    for(/* something */) {
        anotherme.single();
    }
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void single() {
    // do stuff
}
```

You will have to inject another instance of the EJB and call single in order for the container to process the transaction aspects.

Comment: But if I directly call `single` method will transaction attribute be applied? Is not it applied only when call is made through bean's client interface?

Comment: If you are in the context of an EJB call (you called loop thru EJB) it should work, but you can verify it easily. inject TransactionSynchronizationRegistry with (@Resource) and use `getTransactionKey()` to get the current transaction key. Then you can check if its changing.

Comment: >But if I directly call single method will transaction attribute be applied? - No, this won't work if called on the (implicit) `this` directly. You need to use the proxy. From within the bean you can use a trick. See http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_self_invoke_ejb

Comment: Thanks, one more question. Does `SessionContext.getBusinessObject` work with EJB 2.x? Or there is something similar technique to achieve this?

Comment: Don't know but I would assume it should.

Comment: I tried it with EJB 2 and got `java.lang.RuntimeException: NOT IMPLEMENTED
        at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionEnterpriseContext$SessionContextImpl.getBusinessObject(StatelessSessionEnterpriseContext.java:196)`

Comment: Is it not implemented because of usage of ejb 2 or it is due to jboss server? I am using `5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)]`.

Comment: I really don't know, i'm a websphere person